# checkbox to show/hide multiple text inputs

Tags: html

I have this HTML checkbox input with an onClick action.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="vendor_same_address" id="vendor_same_address" value="y" onclick="if(this.checked) { document.getElementById('vendor_address_number').hidden='true' }" />
```

i want to be able to show/hide multiple text inputs on check/uncheck

whats the best way using an onClick action?

Comment: Are you willing to use jQuery?

Comment: yeah JQuery would be fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so using jQuery. To do this, do the following:

1. Remove onClick event from your input tag.
2. Bind this checkbox with jQuery change event
3. Provide same class attribute to each textbox, you want to show/hide
4. By using $.each method you can select that class and show hide textbox inputs

ex:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#vendor_same_address').change(function(){
        $('.uniqueclass').each(function(){
            $(this).show();
        });
    });
});
```

for a quick help refer to http://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: i changed .uniqueclass to .vendor and added a class of .vendor to each input and also changed your .show to .hide but when the checkbox is checked, but they are still showing

Comment: Did you include jquery javascript in head section. To test if jquery present put an alert('something'); before $('.uniqueclass') line.

Comment: working fine now :) how can i do on click .hide and on click again .show ?

Comment: they dont re-appear on uncheck

Comment: use .toggle() instead of .show(), use fiddle to exercise

Answer (score 0):

if you are going to use Javascript, though,

```
... onclick="if(this.checked) { document.getElementById('vendor_address_number').style.visibility='hidden';}" />
```

should be ok
OR

```
... onclick="if(this.checked){
document.getElementById('vendor_address_number').hidden='hidden';}" />
```

anyways, make sure to end your commands with a `;` in javascript. That may be a cause of a failure sometimes.

Regards, Knuckles

Answer (score 0):

in jQuery:

You would obviously need to change the `#example_element` to the inputs you plan on hiding or showing

```
$("#example_element").hide();

$("#vendor_same_addres").change(function() {
  if($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $("#example_element").show();
  } else {
    $("#example_element").hide();
  }
});
```